# Django rest serializer not serializing related fields

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

In view set I am getting fields in request.data (passing foreign key) but serializer.data only gives non related fields
I have 5 fields of which 1 is foreign key and 1 is manytomany relation.

Model-

class Movie(models.Model):

```
popularity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1 )
imdb_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
director = models.ForeignKey(Director)
genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
```

Serializer - 
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Movie
    fields='__all__'
    depth = 1
```

viweset - 
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

```
queryset = Movie.objects.all()
serializer_class = MovieSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```

Comment: add your code in a question. `Model`, `ViewSet` and `Serializer`

Comment: @IvanSemochkin please cehck I have added code